# Can't install MySQL Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS, but when I try to install it using `sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client` (or even `sudo apt install mysql-server`), I get the next errors:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-5.7.postinst: line 143: /usr/share/mysql-common/                                                                                                                                                             configure-symlinks: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-2) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (1.71-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.26-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl (0.77-1build1) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.10-1) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.11-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client (5.7.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro                                                                                                                                                             r from a previous failure.
                           mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I already tried purging all mysql packages and dependencies using

> sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
>
> sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
>
> rm -r /var/lib/mysql
>
> reboot

but so far no luck, can please someone help me to solve this?, i'm really new into Ubuntu, and i can't get this to work. also this displays when i type `service mysql status`:

```
root@ubuntu:~# service mysql status
● mysql.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Jul 24 07:06:10 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jul 24 07:14:05 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: The standard commands in cases like these are `sudo dpkg --configure -a` followed by `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: this is the output: `root@ubuntu:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: or [this](https://i.imgur.com/wCgYUeE.png) after trying to install mysql

Comment: Why not specify the package? `sudo apt install mysql-server-5.7`?

Comment: because then [this](https://i.imgur.com/PZfh3pP.png) happens

Comment: now [this](https://i.imgur.com/4U5pJ0G.png) shows after trying `dpkg --configure -a`